# How to get information about the series a release belongs to via Musicbrainz

Tags: xml, api, musicbrainz

I plan to extend the music library manager [beets](http://beets.io/), which relies on Musicbrainz as backend.

What I want to do is find out the Series a Compilation belongs to given the MBID of the compilation.
When you open a release in the WEB-Interface, the "release group" is written at the bottom of the page.

For example there is [Bravo Hits 45](https://musicbrainz.org/release/bfaa7806-0628-4e81-a553-b88e379b6c3b).
It belongs to the series [Bravo Hits](https://musicbrainz.org/series/1350fce9-08ab-40ba-a7bb-ed3cfb869499) and is no 45.

But how do I get this information given the MBID e.g. `bfaa7806-0628-4e81-a553-b88e379b6c3b` of a release using the XML-API?

(PS: I am not 100% sure if keywords `series` and `release-group` have anything in common.)

I tried to request metadata to include series relations and collection information:
`http://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/release/bfaa7806-0628-4e81-a553-b88e379b6c3b?inc=series-rels+collections` 
No information.

Or maybe via release group?
`http://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/release-group?release=bfaa7806-0628-4e81-a553-b88e379b6c3b` 
No information.

I thought there should even be a browse request for series, but this query doesn't even exist:
`https://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/series?release=1350fce9-08ab-40ba-a7bb-ed3cfb869499`

---

Anyway, I could do a query using the name, getting a lot of inexact results including the right one:
`https://musicbrainz.org/search?query=Bravo+Hits+45&type=series&method=indexed`

**But I guess there should be a way, to do an exact lookup using the MBID of the release, right?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relationship in this case is between the release group and the series, so you can't request that information on the release. However, `http://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/release-group?release=bfaa7806-0628-4e81-a553-b88e379b6c3b&inc=series-rels` (your release group request with a `series-rels` include) does include the information you're looking for, as does `https://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/release-group/a84861c0-72b3-37b2-bbbc-07c03269abab?inc=series-rels`.

Just to clarify: it is also possible for releases to be part of a series, it's just that in this case the relationship is between the release group and the series.

Comment: Wow thanks! `http://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/release-group?release=bfaa7806-0628-4e81-a553-b88e379b6c3b&inc=series-rels` is exactly what I was looking for. And thanks for the hint regarding releases can be part of series, too. I'll respect that in my code.